# get all week Mon-Sun fron Datetime

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get all days of the week of a Datetime?
example: `DateTime.utc(2022, 12, 21)`. The result should be:
`mon(19)-tue(20)-wed(21)-thu(22)-fri(23)-sat(24)-sun(25)`

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all weekdays for a given DateTime, you can use:

```dart
void main() {
  print(getAllWeekDays(DateTime.now()));
}

List<DateTime> getAllWeekDays(DateTime datetime) {
  return List.generate(7, (index) {
    return datetime.subtract(Duration(days: datetime.weekday - index));
  });
}
```

Prints:

```
[2022-12-18 11:46:53.333, 2022-12-19 11:46:53.333, 2022-12-20 11:46:53.333, 2022-12-21 11:46:53.333, 2022-12-22 11:46:53.333, 2022-12-23 11:46:53.333, 2022-12-24 11:46:53.333]
```

---

Note: this isn't a *complete* answer to get *exactly* what you want, as you'll need to *format* the `DateTimes`.
But to do so, you can use the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.
Additionally, take a look at:
[How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)