# How to show only date in Date time class?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, calendar, datetimepicker

i am trying to show a calendar in order to user choose a reservation date by clicking the reserve button . and the reservation day's date is shown below the button.
i am using DateTime class.

i have two questions :
1- i want to "just" show the date of reservation day . i don't need exact hours and time and i don't khow how to do it . i tried with "spilt and a range" but i couldn't.

2- do you khow what is the usage of that toLocal() method there (Text('reservation date : ${selectedtime.toLocal()}'),) in my code? is that necessary there or not?

[image: here is the result of my code:]

here is my whole code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _Example();
}

class _Example extends State<MyPage> {
  DateTime selectedtime = DateTime.now();

  datePicker(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedtime,
        firstDate: DateTime(2023),
        lastDate: DateTime(2025));

    if (picked != null && picked != selectedtime) {
      setState(() {
        selectedtime = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('HDBOOKS'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => datePicker(context),
                child: const Text('reserve')),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 36,
          ),
          Text('reservation date : ${selectedtime.toLocal()}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my code when i wanted to fix the problem with split:

//when i use split i need a range of things to be shown but i don't khow how to use range in split.
it raises error!

```
          Text(
              'reservation date : ${selectedtime.toLocal()}'.split(' ')[0 : 3]),
```

please help me thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions here. The first one (the easier) is to turn the `DateTime` object into a string, then split it and get the first part like this:

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
now.toString().split(' ')[0]
```

And this will do; however, if you want more control, I suggest you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126580/20415955).

Comment: thank you and do you know the answer of my second question too?

Comment: It returns DateTime in the local time zone. The answer to 'Is it necessary there?' depends on your preference. In my opinion, it's better to change the date according to the user's timezone when displaying it. you can read more here [toLocal](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.1/dart-core/DateTime/toLocal.html)  and here  [DateTime-class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.1/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use `DateFormat` class from `intl` package to format.

```
DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd').format(selectedtime.toLocal());
```

2. `toLocal()` ensures the local time of the device, also some countries use daylight savings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String today = '${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}';
```

By this you can get day, month, year, hour, minute etc